# Improving SQL Query joins performance

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

We have been using SQL Server 2014 for our project as a backend source. We have been performing various joins on the tables. We came across a question in one to many and many to one relationship in joins.

Say for example: I have a table named *Industry* and another table called *Products*. *Industry* holds the list of Industry in market and *Products* holds that industry's multiple products.

#### Industry

```
Id
IndustryName
Owner
```

#### Products

Id
IndustryId
ProductId
ProductName

From the above tables, I am performing two queries as shown below:

1. 1 to many

   ```
   Select *
   from Industry
   inner join Products 
       on Industry.Id = Product.IndustryId
   ```
2. many to 1

   ```
   Select * 
   from Product
   inner join Industry 
       on Product.IndustryId = Industry.Id
   ```

Among the above which will be more efficient performance wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. Only the order of the columns in the `SELECT` list changes.

See related questions:

- [Is it correct, order of where clause doesn't matter when it is used with join?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16477/is-it-correct-order-of-where-clause-doesnt-matter-when-it-is-used-with-join)
- [join syntax / style performance consideration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/join-syntax-style-performance-consideration)
- [Is a join optimized to a where clause at runtime?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35596/is-a-join-optimized-to-a-where-clause-at-runtime)

Changes like this will almost 100% produce the same execution plan.

---

*<sub>Communtiy Wiki answer based on an original comment on the question by [@ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube)</sub>*